# create horizontal menu webapplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, navigation

i have a small web application developed with jsps and servlets. i have a homepage which has header section (logo), below that there is a horizontal menu bar which is going to be links to my jsps. when i click on a link, the content of the jsp should load on the same page beneath the menu bar instead of loading the jsp completely in a fresh page. I have shown my layout in the attachment, please guide me what technology/concept to for. i dont need the code, i just want to know how  to achieve it, i will google and learn. Thank you.[image]

Comment: You will want to use ajax in javascript to get content. Easy to research

Answer (score 1):

Check [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

You can bind the onClick event on the links with the jQuery load function, retrieve data from the server, and place the returning content inside a matching element

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```